# Wordpress replace query enters null

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I am using the wordpress replace query to update/add the records But i am facing an error . It updates the records successfully But the values not in array becomes null .Here is my code

```
function ux_add_data($table,$postdata){
    global $wpdb;
    $tablename=$wpdb->prefix.$table;
    $updated_data=$postdata['BX_data'];
    if(isset($updated_data['isActive']) && $updated_data['isActive']==1)
        $updated_data['isActive']=1;
    else
        $updated_data['isActive']=0;    

    $data=$wpdb->replace($tablename,$updated_data,array('%s') );
    if($data)
        return UX_flash('success','Data has been added successfully.');
    else
        return UX_flash('danger','Some errror to save your data.'); 
}
```

if i have columns in database `recordid,ID,name,class,created,modified` and in array i have only `recordid,name,modified` then `ID,class,modified` becomes null .

Please tell me where i am doing wrong.

Thanks

Comment: For one, your if loop is wrong. You have already checked for `$updated_data['isActive']` to be set and equal to 1, there is no need to set it again. Does the query create a new row or actually replace an existing row?

Comment: `Sending a null value will cause the column to be set to NULL`
[read at](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/replace/)

Answer (score 0):

You're using `$wpdb->replace` function, please notice that

> wpdb::replace( string $table, array $data, array|string $format = null )
>
> **$data**
>
> (array) (Required) Data to insert (in column => value pairs). Both $data columns and $data values should be "raw" (neither should be SQL escaped). **Sending a null value will cause the column to be set to NULL** - the corresponding format is ignored in this case.

So, while you're setting some columns, some others will set null.

find more [at here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/replace/).